# How can I create a dashed border with gradient?

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

[image]

I need to create a dashed border gradient like in this picture. Here's my CSS code.

```
.Rectangle-5 {
  margin: 51px 0px 0px 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 370px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4fc3f7, #ab5ca4 49%, #ff512f);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**New answer**

Here is an improvement version of the initial answer with less of code. The idea is to rely on multiple background and adjust [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) of each one.

```css
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius:3px;
  border: 2px dotted #fff;
  background:
   linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box,
   linear-gradient(to bottom, #4fc3f7, #ab5ca4 49%, #ff512f) border-box; 
}
.alt {
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>

<div class="container alt">

</div>
```

---

**Old answer**

You can apply `linear-gradient` as a background to an extern container and then use **dotted** or **dashed** border on inner container. As per your needs you have to use the white as color for the border and also as the background of the content like this :

```css
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4fc3f7, #ab5ca4 49%, #ff512f);
}

.inner {
  border: 2px dotted #fff;
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
}
.inner-alt {
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-alt">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to pay attention to the **height** of the inner container. It should be 100% but don't forget the border in calculation, that's why i used `calc(100% - 4px)` (2px for top border and 2px for bottom border).

So if you change border height value you need also to update the height accordingly.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 VXp intended to simply change dotted property of boder by dashed. it's almost the same, you will only change how it looks. You can try and you will see the difference

Comment: @TemaniAfif if we inner will give class inner  the  border: 1px dashed #fff we take exactly the same result  as the picture.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 yes, and as i commented both can be correct. it just depend on the looking (By the way i updated the anwser to say it). I just focused on the trick of using the background then the border ;)

Answer (score -2):

Add the following rule to your CSS

```
.Rectangle-5{
  border: 2px dotted #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) padding-box,
   linear-gradient(92.35deg, #3370fe 1.28%, #00e599 98.95%) border-box;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).